# ASP validation client side

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I've made a site web that's going to be only used by the company. I've done my validation only on server side and **I tested for it to be safe**. I did some meetings to teach the users how to use the site correctly. Plus, I have some ugly popups made with C# (for particular situations).

### Now, I'm wondering if I should add some validation on client side?

- Is it to late to add it?
- In my case, what would be the advantages?
- Does user should know how to use the site (instead of validation that would guide/help them)?
- Does client side validations can avoid me to teach to new users and to employees from other factories?

Comment: ask your stakeholders and users. we aren't them.

Comment: in general, does it add something? is it relevant?

Comment: a better user experience.

Comment: I'm sorry felix but this question is not exactly a technical question, it is opinion based question. If you like to discuss about it I'll be happy to assist you.
You can find me in chatroom named: Chatroom777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here are the answers to your questions to the best of my knowledge:

**Now, I'm wondering if I should add some validation on client side?**

Client side validation enhances the user experience and saves you a lot of round trips to the server. You should definately consider adding client side validation. However you should never trust what is comming to you from client side; server side validation is a must. You already have that; don't remove it.

**Is it to late to add it?**

No, it is never too late to correct your mistakes or make enhancements to your application.

**In my case, what would be the advantages?**

To name a few -- Better user experience, less load on server, a layer of added code security.

**Does user should know how to use the site (instead of validation that would guide/help them)?
Does client side validations can avoid me to teach to new users and to employees from other factories?**

Yes, a good application should not require training to user, or only a minimal amount of training should be needed. The application itself should drive the user in right direction. Client side validations and functionality helps achieve this to a large extent.

Answer (score 1):

you should add client validations because it restricts multiple postback from server.

Comment: does it really make a difference/impact?

Comment: yes, enhances the user experience and saves you a lot of round trips to the server